# How to convert uint8 to int in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, converters

I have converted the image from RGB to grayscale and have the image-matrix in uint8. I'm trying to make some image processing with convolution which means that I want to use the values as int when I'm summing up everything. So, **how can I convert from uint8 to int in Matlab?**

Comment: `int8` or `int16`

Comment: ... or `int32` or `int64`. But if you are going to compute convolutions, use `double`. In general you should use `double` for most computations in MATLAB. Also, to compute convolutions, use `conv` or `conv2` or `convn` (depending on the dimensionality) -- it will handle the data type for you.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab support multiple integer formats. The main difference is the required space in memory and if the sign (+ or -) is used.

For example, uint8 means that the integer is unsigned and that it uses 8 bit to store the value. The number of used bits determines the maximal value. The uint8 can store a number between 0 and 2^8-1.

You can find a whole list of all supported integer [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html)

If you would like to convert your uint8 into another format you can just write the desired format as a function and pass the value as parameter:

```
I2 = uint16(I);
```

Answer (score -1):

In matlab you can use double type.
for example type cast with:

```
I2=double(I);
```

It is easy to understand that you can use
    int8(I)
    int16(I)
too.

Comment: A double is not an integer.

Comment: In MATLAB you *should* use the double type. Especially for convolutions.